# Get string minimum from recursive hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, hql, recursive-datastructures

I have an entity that has a ManyToMany relationship with itself:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "asset")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Asset implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "provided_c")
private EnumerationClass providedC; // A0, A1, A2, ...

@ManyToMany
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@JoinTable(name = "asset_dependencies",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "assets_id",  `referencedColumnName = "id"),`
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dependencies_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Asset> dependencies = new HashSet<>();
```

When I call this query in my Spring Data repository I do get all Assets and the depending ones.

```
@Query(value = "select distinct asset from Asset supporting_asset left join fetch asset.dependencies")
List<Asset> findAllWithEagerRelationships();
```

But I need to get another calculated field.
All assets have a categorisation (providedC: A0 -A3). The calculated field would be the lowest category of all assets, this asset depends on.

Is there a good way to achieve this? 
Or what would be the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a @Formula to achieve this functionality. You can place a query evaluating the lowest dependent category and it will bve triggered on load of the entity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know by chance what query I would use, because the dependencies are several levels deep (meaning: the asset has a list of assets as dependencies which one their own have dependencies too)?